# Why does my output have garbage value, and how to fix it?

Tags: c, struct, file-handling, garbage

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct info {
    char album[30];
    int released;
    char group[30];
};

int main() {
    FILE * fpt; 
    int size;
    struct info band[size];
    int i;

    printf("How many groups would you like to input: ");
    scanf("%d",&size); 

    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {

        printf ("Input what group: ");
        scanf(" %s", band[i].group);    

        printf("Input released date: ");
        scanf(" %d", &band[i].released);

        printf("Input what album: ");
        scanf(" %s", band[i].album);

    }

    fpt = fopen("records.dat", "w");
    // printf("Group\t\tReleased\t\tAlbum\n");

    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        fprintf(fpt,"%s\t\t%d\t\t%s\n", band[i].group, band[i].released, 
        band[i].album);
    }

    printf("File created.\n");
    fclose(fpt);
}
```

this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8pnf.png):

ø       -605554032      entropy // but the next line outputs are correct

Comment: `int size; struct info band[size];` The second statement results in undefined behaviour as the `size` variable has not been initialised at that point. Move it to be after the `scanf`.

Comment: Other notes: Always check the return value of function calls. In this case, it is very important to check `scanf` and `fopen` results.

Comment: @kaylum        please change that into answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have here an issue with memory allocation to your band array. When you write "struct info band [size]",you essentially tell to your computer: "please create for me size structs and find a place for them on the stack". However, this can't happen here due to two reasons:

1. As the comment above me stated, the variable size is uninitialized when that line takes place.
2. Even if you had code like: `size=3; struct info band[size]` things wouldn't work since the program has to know how much space it should create for the band array on the stack **in compile time** while the size variable is being set **at running time** - Use malloc to overcome this issue: `scanf(%d, &size); struct info * band = (struct info*)malloc(sizeof(struct info) * size);` This would create just 4 bytes (i.e. : pointer size) for your array on the stack while allocating dynamically the relevant memory for your actual array on the heap.

At the end of the main function, don't forget to add `free(band);`

Good luck!